# search functionality is not working in the mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below jquery code it search the products , it is working in desktop view and i also done responsive mobile view,from mobile the searching functionality is not working, please anyone help me to solve this problem.

```js
$("#search-criteria").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var isMatch = false;

    $(".fbbox .fix label").each(function() {
        var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        
        if(s.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
          isMatch = true;
           $(this).closest('.fbbox')['show'](""); 
        } else {
          
           $(this).closest('.fbbox')['hide']("");
       }
      });
});
```

Comment: Try using the `input` event instead of `keyup`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this. It may helps

```
  $(document).on('keyup','#search-criteria', function()  
     {
       // code
    });
```

Comment: I have used but it is not working,and it is not entering in to if condition , now i checked by using alert.

Comment: Likewise Rory McCrosan said, you can use input event .                              `$('#search-criteria').on('input', function(){ doSomething(); });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the value to lower case as well :D

```
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34821995)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code.

```
$("#search-criteria").keyup(function() {
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
var isMatch = false;

$(".fbbox .fix label").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    var container = $(this).closest('.fbbox');

    if (text.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
        isMatch = true;
        container.show();
    } else {
        container.hide();
    }
});

if (isMatch) {
    $(".no-match-message").hide();
} else {
    $(".no-match-message").show();
}
```

});